# Entity Framework, full-text search and temporary tables

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, full-text-search, temp-tables

I have a LINQ-2-Entity query builder, nesting different kinds of Where clauses depending on a fairly complex search form. Works great so far.

Now I need to use a SQL Server fulltext search index in some of my queries. Is there any chance to add the search term directly to the LINQ query, and have the score available as a selectable property?

If not, I could write a stored procedure to load a list of all row IDs matching the full-text search criteria, and then use a LINQ-2-Entity query to load the detail data and evaluate other optional filter criteria *in a loop* per row. That would be of course a very bad idea performance-wise.

Another option would be to use a stored procedure to insert all row IDs matching the full-text search into a temporary table, and then let the LINQ query join the temporary table. Question is: how to join a temporary table in a LINQ query, as it cannot be part of the entity model?

Answer (score 2):

I think I would probably suggest a hybrid approach.

1. Write a stored procedure which returns all the information you need.
2. Map an entity to the results. The entity can be created for this sole purpose. Alternately, use version 4 of the Entity Framework, which allows mapping complex types to start procedure results. The point is that instead of trying to coerce the procedure results in to existing entity types, were going to handle them as their own type.
3. Now you can build a LINQ to Entities query.

Sample query:

```
var q = from r in Context.SearchFor("searchText")
        let fooInstance = (r.ResultType == "Foo")
            ? Context.Foos.Where(f => f.Id == r.Id)
            : null
        where ((fooInstance == null) || (fooInstance.SpecialCriterion == r.SpecialCriterion))    
        select {
            // ...
```

This is off the top of my head, so the syntax might not be right. The important point is treating search results as an entity.

Alternately: Use a more flexible FTS system, which can do the "special", per-type filtering when building the index.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen code like this for EF4:

```
var query = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<Person>(
        "SELECT * FROM People WHERE FREETEXT(*,{0})", 
        searchText
    ).AsQueryable();
```

This may be simpler than creating a stored proc or UDP in some cases.

Comment: This is wrong so many ways. ExecuteStoreQuery returns IEnumerable, so no paging, no real .Skip or .Take ... .AsQueryable() does just cast to another type.

Comment: @Crank, it's not wrong if you don't need to perform DB-side skip/take or further processing. And if you do need that, then you can amend the SQL string. If you have a better solution that achieves full-text search, please contribute your own answer.

Comment: Yes, when you dont need to do something, you obviously dont need to use it.

Good ol' LINQ was better than that. You could use TVF in expression trees as real queryable ...

We are trying to find LINQ alternative with real Code First support and the only available (open source) are fluent hibernate and entity framework.

Both are inferior though. EF5 cannot use TVF properly in code first settigns, only in db first. You cant combine them without unnesessary troubles.